# Functions (Substring or userdefined functions) in SSIS Error

Tags: ssis, user-defined-functions

I used Substring and UserDefined function to perform few string manipulations. However, the datatype generated in the OldDB Source Query for these columns are DT_NTEXT. The destination columns are DT_WSTR and it gives error

```
    An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "col09" column. 
The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". 
The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_WVARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.
```

Is there any way to use the functions in the query and also match the datatype.

```
    select substring('here is my text', 0, 4) 'col1', 
dbo.processstring('hello world') 'col2' from table1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the advanced properties of your Source component, and modify the SSIS datatype of the output column to DT_WSTR.